# Calculating offset in file from VCN

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

I'm doing some work with the NTFS MFT, and the $LogFile.  I'm currently trying to understand the way in which changes against an MFT record are performed using the Logical Cluster Number (LCN) and the Virtual Cluster Number (VCN).  It's my understanding that the LCN is the actual cluster on the drive, whereas the VCN is the cluster from the start of the file.

So using this as an example.

```
 Target VCN:2271
 Target LCN: 788703
```

The maths involved here should just be to do:

```
2271 * 4096 = 9302016
```

I know that the $MFT starts at LCN 3221225472, so:

```
3221225472 + 9302016 = 3230527488
```

But that gives me an offset way beyond the end of the file.  I guess I'm misunderstanding something here, could anyone help shine some light?

Thanks

Comment: not add byte offset to cluster

Comment: So my maths is correct, I just don't need to add the MFT starting offset?

Comment: you nothing need add at all.